# Jenkins console output error pathspec 'null'

Tags: git, jenkins, pipeline

This is my first ask so thank you for being patient (not a programmer/coder).  New to Git and Jenkins and need help getting unstuck.  Trying a deployment from master to dev region using Jenkins Pipeline.  I have an artifacts file containing two assets to deploy in the correct format and placed in the right folder. The release version is looking for a tag which is created.  Getting the following build (with parameters) error at this step "Checking out the Release tag assets to local repo":
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DeploymentPipeline>git checkout null 
error: pathspec 'null' did not match any file(s) known to git

I have tried everything and searched solutions on tech sites with no luck. Everything seems okay in the local (files tracked) and remote (committed). Why is the pathspec not finding my files? What am I missing? :-(

[tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7x8L.png)

[Github branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nxhk.png)

[Git cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX1qE.png)

[build parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGiaE.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0n3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without the job config is hard to exactly tell you whats is wrong but looks like you need to pass the parameter releaseVersion to `git checkout` command.

Something like

`git checkout %releaseVersion%`

Tip: Use [git parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/)